# Pesquisa erro cep invalido

Tags: python

Pessoal estou tentando fazer uma aplicação para consultar uma lista de cep's que possuo, mas quando o ex: cep=40717000 não existe é exibido  um erro e não consigo seguir para o proximo registro da tabela, alguém pode ajudar por favor? Obrigado

```
import requests
import json
import pyodbc

conn = pyodbc.connect("DRIVER={SQL Server};Server=54.233.154.67;database=xxxxx;uid=yyyyy;pwd=zzzz")
cursor = conn.cursor()

cursor.execute('select * from cep_sem_referencia')

for row in cursor.fetchall():

    cep = row[1]

    r = requests.get("https://viacep.com.br/ws/%s/json/" % cep)

    #try:
    if r.status_code == requests.codes.ok:

        j = json.loads(r.text)

        cep1 = j['cep']
        uf = j['uf']

        cursor = conn.cursor()

        cursor.execute("INSERT INTO endereco VALUES('%s','%s')" % (cep1, uf))

        conn.comit()

    else:
        print('cep não encontrado')

    #except Exception:

    #print('')
```

Comment: "*é exibido um erro*", que erro?

Answer (score 3):

Quando um CEP teoricamente válido (8 caracteres) é enviado para essa API (ViaCep) ela retornará os dados ou um campo *erro* com valor *true*. Quando trabalhei com essa API tive problemas para tratar os erros: ela não retorna um status code de erro quando o CEP não é encontrado, ela retorna um objeto de erro. Experimente fazer o tratamento de dados verificando se no JSON retornado está presente o campo *erro*.

A imagem abaixo mostra uma requisição realizada com o CEP 40717000.

[image: JSON de retorno com CEP teoricamente válido (8 caracteres), mas que não existe]

Edit: Código

```
import requests
import json
import pyodbc

conn = pyodbc.connect("DRIVER={SQL Server};Server=54.233.154.67;database=xxxxx;uid=yyyyy;pwd=zzzz")
cursor = conn.cursor()

cursor.execute('select * from cep_sem_referencia')

for row in cursor.fetchall():

    cep = row[1]

    r = requests.get("https://viacep.com.br/ws/%s/json/" % cep)

    #try:
    if r.status_code == requests.codes.ok and 'erro' not in r.json():

        j = json.loads(r.text)

        cep1 = j['cep']
        uf = j['uf']

        cursor = conn.cursor()

        cursor.execute("INSERT INTO endereco VALUES('%s','%s')" % (cep1, uf))

        conn.comit()

    else:
        print('cep não encontrado')

    #except Exception:

    #print('')
```

Comment: Ola, sim colega é exactamente esse o erro que estou tendo, mas como faço para o programa ignorar e passar para o próximo registro? obrigado.

Comment: Obrigado Vinicius ajudou muito. abs